# Toolbars not showing in visual studio ultimate 12

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have recently downloaded trial version of visual studio ultimate 12 it is working fine when i am coding but i can not view the toolbox which was there in visual studio 10 to drag and drop buttons ... and other controls .
Am i missing some thing ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i got it .
It came from the hot keys alt+ctrl+x.